# visual c++ 2013 memory leak wostringstream, imbue & locale facets

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, locale, wostringstream

Related to my previous question, I assumed that memory leak occurs in std::string, but taking a deeper look, I got some strange results. Let's begin:

Consider we have a global

```
static volatile std::wostringstream *Log = nullptr;
```

and in a WriteToLog() function we have following code:

```
    std::wostringstream* new_log = new std::wostringstream(std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
    new_log->imbue(CConsumer::GetUtf8Locale());

    std::wostringstream* old_log = (std::wostringstream*)Log;

    while((std::wostringstream *)::InterlockedCompareExchangePointer((PVOID volatile *)&Log, new_log, (PVOID)old_log) != new_log)
    {
        ::SleepEx(10, FALSE);
    }

    std::string logtext(Hooker::Utf16ToUtf8(old_log->str()));
```

which utilizes proprietary:

```
    static std::locale FORCEINLINE GetUtf8Locale()
    {
        static std::unique_ptr<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> code_cvt(new std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>(std::codecvt_mode::generate_header | std::codecvt_mode::little_endian));
        return std::locale(std::locale(), code_cvt.get());
    }
```

Since log events occurs occasionally, it generates enormous memory leak (from initial 5MB/500 handles it jumps to 200MB/300,000 handles in a matter of minutes).

Previously, I assumed it's a leak in relation to std::string, but, using Visual Studio Profiler, it shows that all leaks are caused by GetUtf8Locale().

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: Your cast worries me.

Comment: I'm not sure why the `InterlockedCompareExchangePointer` is there, it appears to be some sort of faultly locking mechanism?

Comment: Do you ever call `delete new_log;`?

Comment: I have serious doubts that this code leaks where you claim.

Comment: Are you deleting new_log anywhere in your code after? (Just noticed someone else asked this already)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, but I delete old_log (new log has to be persistent).

Comment: @JohanLundberg no, it cannot be used, because unique_ptr would loose content on function exit

Comment: @TiodorJovovic All of that looks pretty flawed for my taste.

Comment: @MooingDuck My sentiments exactly, but VS Profiler points to it and shows data about memory consumption and allocated handles. Also, for the InterlockedCompareExchangePointer, it is required in order to atomically interchange pointers between threads

Comment: @TiodorJovovic _"no, it cannot be used,  ..."_ May be you should have something like `unique_ptr<std::wostringstream> Log;` and use `Log.reset(new_log);`. Also I don't understand why a new instance should be created wit every `WriteToLog()` call, that's pretty inefficient.

Comment: I used this code in Visual Studio 2013 and observed zero memory growth. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82db6e1c4d007eb6

Comment: No wait `<facepalm>` I just realized the flaws in the use of the Interlocked Exchange _cause a memory leak_

Comment: @MooingDuck many thanks for your time, will try it immediately and report

Answer (score 0):

## This answer is wrong and I overlooked the "Compare" part of InterlockedCompareExchangePointer.  However, I think it's a step in the right direction.

So we start with an object who's `Log` member points at `0x87654321`.  Then two threads call `WriteToLog`

```
Thread1                                Thread2
...new_log=new ... 
(now new_log=0x15331564)
                                       ...new_log=new ...
                                       (now new_log=0x25874963)
...old_log=Log;
(now old_log=0x87654321)
                                       ...old_log=Log;
                                       (now old_log=0x87654321)

InterlockedCompareExchangePointer
(now new_log=0x87654321)
(now Log=0x15331564)

                                       InterlockedCompareExchangePointer
                                       (now new_log=0x15331564)
                                       (now Log=0x25874963)
...stuff...                            ...stuff...
delete old_log 
(now 0x87654321 is deleted)
                                       delete old_log
                                       (now 0x87654321 is deleted TWICE!)
```

And the `Log` member points at `0x25874963`, so...  log `0x15331564` is leaked!

Your use of `InterlockedCompareExchangePointer` is incorrect.  I think this is right, depending on the code you haven't shown.

```
std::wostringstream* new_log = new std::wostringstream(std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
new_log->imbue(CConsumer::GetUtf8Locale());

std::wostringstream* old_log = ::InterlockedExchangePointer((PVOID volatile *)&Log.get(), new_log);

std::string logtext(Hooker::Utf16ToUtf8(old_log->str()));

delete old_log;
```